# Why my AptanaStudio3.0 can't debug Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-debug

I have Google this question for almost a whole day, but still not answer. My ruby version is 1.9.3 and Rails is 3.2.1, on a Mac 10.6 OS.

now my gem list is:

```
linecache19 (0.5.13)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.26)
ruby-debug-ide19 (0.4.12)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
```

I think I have all the things I may need, but the debugger is still not working on my AptanaStudio3.

When I debug a ruby program, I got this error:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.9) listens on :51042
Exception in DebugThread loop: undefined method `is_binary_data?' for "Array (10 element(s))":String
```

When I debug a rails server, I got this error:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.9) listens on :51175
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/interface.rb:128:in `<module:Debugger>'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/interface.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/processor.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/processor.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:6:in `require_relative'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
    /Users/Chris/workspace-aptana/RailsDemo/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Chris/workspace-aptana/RailsDemo/script/rails:6:in `require'
    /Users/Chris/workspace-aptana/RailsDemo/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:123:in `debug_load'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:123:in `debug_program'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/ruby-debug-ide19-0.4.12/bin/rdebug-ide:87:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
    /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `<main>'
Uncaught exception: superclass mismatch for class RemoteInterface
```

Anyone can help, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that ruby-debug-ide and ruby-debug19 don't play well, something about conflicting name-space issues. To get debugging to work on Aptana3 (my specific version is 3.0.9), is to remove references to ruby-debug19 from you Gemfile and run:

```
bundle install
```

to make sure it's also removed from the Gemfile.lock file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error as well, after upgrading my Ubuntu 13.04 system from ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.3.  Here is my solution...

1. Remove all debug gems from Gemfile.  (i.e. no ruby-debug-ide, ruby-debug-ide19, debugger, etc.)  Run bundle install.
2. Run gem install ruby-debug-ide from the command line to install the gem into the system.
3. NOTE: the gem is installed in the system - which makes it accessible to Aptana, but not in the bundle.

Aptana debugging works normally.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the same version except it run on Linux Fedora 16, i have the same error when i add the "view variable" (Menu:Window/Show-view/Other/Variables) in the standard perspective.

After the installation of the gem 'ruby-debug-ide19' (0.4.12) it works fine.

I have those gems installed :

arcadia (0.11.1.1)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
coderay (1.0.5)
columnize (0.3.6)
json (1.6.5)
linecache19 (0.5.13, 0.5.12)
minitest (2.11.3, 2.5.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12, 3.9.4)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.26, 0.11.25)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.16)
ruby-debug-ide19 (0.4.12)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubygems-update (1.8.18)

Hope this help